# Linq to SQL lambda join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Having trouble with this, I've tried following several examples but I am just not getting it. It makes perfect sense using the non-lambda way, but how do I do a join using lambda expressions?

```
var myCats = GetAllCats();
var myHouses = GetAllHouses();

// pseudosql:  select * from a inner join b on a.id = b.id
```

I have tried this:

```
var fullData = myCats.Join(myHouses, a => a.id, b => b.id, (a, b) => a);
```

which I kind of got through looking at other examples on SO, but fullData  is type `IEnumerable<Cat>` so I can't pull any properties from Houses off it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var fullData = myCats.Join(
                 myHouses, 
                 cat => cat.id, 
                 house => house.id, 
                 (cat, house) => 
                   new 
                   { 
                     Cat = cat, 
                     House = house 
                   });
```

Access via `fullData.First().Cat...` or `fullData.First().House...`.

Comment: Thank you for using variables with more context than `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: changed the lambda parameters as well, so it's more readable.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, that the result of your join - the last parameter of the Join method - is a `Cat`, that's why `fullData` is of type `IEnumerable<Cat>`. If you want to access both, return an anonymous type:

```
var fullData = myCats.Join(myHouses, a => a.id, 
                                     b => b.id,
                                     (a, b) => new { Cat = a, House = b});
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because the final argument `(a, b) => a` means map the return result to the cats only, i.e. it's `(cat, house) => cat`

You can return a temporary object with the pair e.g.

```
(cat, house) => new { cat, house }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to define just what it is you want to select from them.

You can change your latter to:

```
var fullData = myCats.Join(myHouses, cat => cat.id, house => house.id, (cat, house) => new {cat, house})
```

which will make `fullData` an IQueryable of an anonymous type that looks like:

```
class anonymous
{
  Cat cat,
  House house
}
```

The equivalent in LINQy format is:

```
from cat in myCats join house in myHouses
  on cat.id equals house.id
  select new {cat, house}
```

You can also specify just what you want to select, to avoid waste:

```
from cat in myCats join house in myHouses
  on cat.id equals house.id
  select new {cat.id, cat.name, house.address}
```